# Integrating phoneGap with native iOS app

Tags: ios, cordova

i'm trying to create an app which uses the combination of native functionality and the phoneGap framework. The native app has a button, upon the click of which the phoneGap ui has to be added to the view. Is there any way to achieve this? Are there any tutorials for the same?

Comment: why do you need to do the first step without phonegap?

Comment: to access the basic UI functionality of iOS - Scroll, TabBar etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Although you might be getting yourself into some headaches. My app kind of goes the other way around, it's mostly phonegap, but occasionally i'll pop open a view that is native. Here is the link to code that shows an excellent example of how to switch between the iOS and phonegap worlds.

[new updated recommended article](https://neilbo21.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/how-i-make-web-apps-for-ios-phonegap-xcode-bonus-childbrowser-video/) (see update below)

These files represent a standard plugin used in phonegap. In this particular plugin, a native view is opened on top of a phonegap view. Notice you have a custom xib and everything. This plugin can be modified to display any xib with any functionality you could think of.

If you implement this plugin you will easily see how to jump back and forth. I've successfully heavily modified these classes to add LOTS of native capabilities to my phonegap project. Also you should probably check out the official phonegap guide to phonegap plugins. [Here](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins)

**Important Edit**

Was informed original linkwas broken (not terribly surprised as this answer is very old and i've long since moved away from Phonegap) so I replaced the original link with an article that shows how to do these plugins well. In the article it explains the link is broken and gives several links where these older files are maintained, but in fact those are broken as well. [Here](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/ARCHIVE/iOS/ChildBrowser) is a branch of one of them I found that still hosts the original files on an "archive" branch. But I haven't investigated whether these files are wildly different from my original work. Good luck!

Comment: whoops, deleted a line. "In this particular plugin, a native view is opened on top of a phonegap view. Notice you have a custom xib and everything. This plugin can be modified to display any xib with any functionality you could think of.

Comment: Your link is unfortunately broken.  Could you please update it to a possibly working URL?

Comment: Done. I wish you the best in your plugin crusade. Let me know if the new links are useful and I'll update further. Didn't want to spend too much time on the problem as i've fallen so far from the phone gap tree, but these phone gap questions are still pretty darn popular and i'll try to help.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how Phonegap is meant to be used.

To achieve what you are asking for you just need to create a Phonegap app and add the extra native functionality by writing a Phonegap plugin in Objective-C. You may add as much native code as you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually wanting to do the same thing as the original poster. Theoretically it would be comparatively easy, but non-trival to do. I'd love it if there was a PhoneGapView that one could integrate into an existing project. Bonus points if said PhoneGapView could be integrated in Interface Builder as a re-sizeable and re-positional object, basically think of it as an Object that extends UIWebView.

This is wishful thinking on my part seeing as this is how the higher-ups want my project.

Comment: I'm not too far from being able to do this. I've also been thinking about this in the back of my mind.