# how to open a native ios viewcontroller in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Like described in the title, I want to open a native ios viewcontroller when the user clicks a button in my index.html file. I think I need to write a custom plugin for that. Anyone can give me more details? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the code of ChildBrowser plugin, which is actually a native view which pops over the phonegap view. You can modify the plugin to show more complex native view. The plugin includes the xib file and other objective-c classes.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser

For more detail check this post:

[Integrating phoneGap with native iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959511/integrating-phonegap-with-native-ios-app)